# Run function when element is loaded into document from dynamically created page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read here: [jQuery's .on function doesn't seem to like 'load' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738512/jquerys-on-function-doesnt-seem-to-like-load-event) that .load doesn't work, "In all browsers, the load event does not bubble".

I'm trying NOT to use $(function(){tabs();}); on every page that I need the 'tabs' function to run on. So how do I run a function from a page when the div .tabswrap class is loaded into the document?

The page dynamically loaded has a div class named 'tabswrap':

The tabs function:

```
function tabs(){
//do something
}
```

This does work if I put the script on the dynamically loaded page itself (which I'm trying to avoid):

```
<script>
$(function(){
   tabs();
});
</script>
```

These don't work:

```
$('.tabswrap').on('load', function(){
   tabs();
});

$('.tabswrap').load(function(){
   tabs();
});
```

Comment: We had to solve this for a group of plugins that needed to be arbitrarily applied to loaded pages. Solution: We trigger our own "panel.loaded" event in the Ajax load, passing the new panel as a property. The top-level page code catches the panel.loaded event and applies plugins based on matching classes within in the loaded page.

Comment: "The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object." The documentation for jQuery `load` does not make any mention of being able to detect when a DIV is loaded. SOURCE: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. The same goes for javascript `onload`.

Comment: If you also provide the code of the `tabs()` function it would help clarify the question (and potentially allow for better answers). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm getting from your story is that you load dynamic content with a div.tabswrap and whenever that new content is loaded, you want to execute the tabs() function, correct?

The reason why it doesn't work is you're trying to bind to an element that does not yet exist. You can only bind to events on elements that exist. Also the load event is not triggered when you insert a node into the dom, so that would not work even after the dom is updated. Try something like:

```
<script> 
function tabs() {
    // something
}

function loadNewContent() {
   // get dynamic content from somewhere
   $('.content').html(newContent);
   if ($('.tabswrap', $(newContent)).size() > 0) {
       tabs();
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Depending on the implementation of their missing `tabs` function it may well be *capable* of supporting dynamic content, e.g. via delegated events, but without the code, who knows :)

Comment: We don't know, but from what I understand he's trying to bind to a "load" event on all future .tabswrap elements before they are in the dom (this fails), and then call the tabs() function (the internals of which are irrelevant to the question).

Comment: I can load the page and search through the response from .load(). I used if(response.indexOf('tabswrap')>-1){tabs();}; to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can rise your own event via [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) when you are loading the dynamic content and do your stuff.

```
var data=".myclassname";
$('body').trigger('tabswrapOnLoad');
....
$('body').on('tabswrapOnLoad', data, function(){ do stuff });
```

Comment: Advice: 1) Never use `'body'` for delegated events. Use `document` instead as `body` has some bugs related to styling. 2) You have not provided a source for the `data` in your example.

Comment: and 3) I am guessing you made this answer up based on my earlier comment, rather than from experience, as it is incomplete and will not work as-shown :) I have added a working answer using `trigger`. As-shown you are using a *delegated* event with `data` defining a jQuery selector!

Comment: Impressive. & I didn't read your comments before :p I took it from my project which used to trigger its own event. But now I have to change body to document. Thanks for your comments @trueblueaussie

Comment: As it was from an existing project I would be interested in how you do it differently. Can you complete your code so that I can see where `data` comes from? As-is your event handler is incorrect.

Comment: data supposed to be my class name. does it solves your doubt? @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 1):

As I was saying in comment: We had to solve this for a group of plugins that needed to be arbitrarily applied to loaded pages.

**Solution:** We trigger our own "panel.loaded" event inside the Ajax load(s), passing the new panel as a property. The top-level page code catches the panel.loaded event and applies plugins based on matching classes within in the loaded page.

### e.g.

Inside your Ajax load:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("panel.loaded", {$panel: data});
$(document).trigger(e);
```

Inside your master page:

```
$(document).on('panel.loaded' function(e){
    // 1) Find a specific part of the loaded panel
    tabs(e.$panel.find('.tabswrap'));

    // Or 2) simply pass the loaded panel to tabs
    tabs(e.$panel);

    // Or 3) you don't really care about the panel loaded and 
    //       will simply apply tabs again to the entire page 
    tabs();
});
```

This implementation implies a version of tabs() that can take the loaded panel as an argument. Otherwise it may be reapplying to the entire page. That is your call as you have not provided the code for `tabs()`.

### Simple Mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z4GK7/3/

### Simpler version.

You can also pass an additional, separate, property object to `trigger`, avoiding the need to create an `Event` object.

### e.g.

```
$(document).trigger("panel.loaded", {$panel: data});
```

**and use with:**

```
$(document).on('panel.loaded' function(e, params){
    // 1) Find a specific part of the loaded panel
    tabs(params.$panel.find('.tabswrap'));

    // Or 2) simply pass the loaded panel to tabs
    tabs(params.$panel);

    // Or 3) you don't really care about the panel loaded and 
    //       will simply apply tabs again to the entire page 
    tabs();
});
```

Comment: .load or .post can load the page dynamically, either way there is a response body to check for the tabswrap class. this solution seems interesting, but can you provide a jsfiddle using this technique because I couldn't figure out how to implement this.

Comment: @Patriotec: Added a simple example. You can basically do anything in `panel.loaded` event (with or without passing the loaded panel as a parameter).

Comment: Tried it and it works, but whats the advantage using your method over simply searching for the div class name in the response body? Performance-wise, isn't this slower?

Comment: This method does not require you to search the DOM for the newly loaded elements (the selector for which may be duplicated on the page!). It just targets the specifically loaded panel. Trigger bubbling only hits ancestors, so is potentially *faster* than a DOM search, so your concerns over efficiency in this situation are misplaced. :) This method also means you can support any number of plugins for the loaded panel, without having to place custom code in all loaders (which the current answer requires). You only need the single trigger broadcast.